# SPA Template VS2013 custom properties IdentityUser

Tags: single-page-application, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to add custom properties to the Identity User 2013 Spa Template. The Identity User model is not in the project when I F12 I get the model in the assembly which is not editable. I have read the tutorial to add a birth date to the Identity model however this example speaks about changing the Identity User model from a Web Forms prospective and it seems to have a UserIdentity model to edit. How do I add custom properties to the  AspNetUser table?

Answer (score 0):

I found the same. Most of the SPA template resources online seem to relate to the earlier (VS2012) version of the template which is quite confusing. However, by comparing the code generated by the MVC template I worked out what I needed to do which was.

1. In the Models folder create your own "ApplicationIdentity" and "ApplicationDbContext" classes. Include any additional properties that you want in your ApplicationIdentity class definition. In the example code below I have added a string for the email address.

   ```
   using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

   namespace SimpleSPA.Models {

      public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
      {
         public string Email { get; set; }
      }

      public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
      {
         public ApplicationDbContext():base("DefaultConnection")
         {
         }
      }
   }
   ```
2. Use the solution Search and Replace to replace all references to "IdentityUser" with your new ApplicationUser.
3. Update the Startup static constructor in Startup.Auth.cs so that the UserManagerFactory initialisation includes your new ApplicationDbContext as below.

   ```
   UserManagerFactory = () => new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
   ```
4. Rebuild the solution, check it builds OK.
5. Enable Entity Framework Code First migrations using the "Enable-Migrations" command in the Package Manager (PM) Console.
6. Add the initial migration using the PM command "Add-Migration Initial".
7. Initialise the database using the PM command "Update-Database".

Following this if you connect to the generated database you should see that the AspNetUsers table includes columns for your additional ApplicationUser properties. I haven't gone much further yet but I would expect that I will be able to access my new properties by using ApplicationUser instead the base IdentityUser.

Comment: I have tried this and not been able to get it to work. Anybody who has been successfull?